# Python interact with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to interact with a process.
I can start the process and print out the first two lines (something like 'process successfully started').
Now I want to send a new command to the process which should return again something like 'command done' but nothing happens.

Please help me.

```
import subprocess

def PrintAndPraseOutput(output, p):
    print(output)
    if 'sucessfully' in output:
        p.stdin.write('command')

cmd = ["./programm"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, universal_newlines=True, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while p.poll() is None:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    PrintAndPraseOutput(output, p)
```

Update:
same problem, no output after 'process successfully started'

```
import subprocess

def print_and_parse_output(output, p):
    print(output)
    if 'successfully' in output:
        p.stdin.write('command\n')


with subprocess.Popen(["./programm"], universal_newlines=True, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    while proc.poll() is None:
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        print_and_parse_output(output, proc)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug this without knowing what the `programm` command does. Did you write it, or can you modify it? Maybe it's not adding newlines to the end of its output, or flushing `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your I/O should be line buffered, so `PrintAndPraseOutput` should send a `'\n'` at the end of the string.

BTW, you have a couple of spelling errors. That function should be named `print_and_parse_output` to conform to [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), and "successfully" has 2 c's.

```
def print_and_parse_output(output, p):
    print(output)
    if 'successfully' in output:
        p.stdin.write('command\n')
```

When using `subprocess` like this it's a good idea to put it in a `with` statement. From [the subprocess.Popen` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> Popen objects are supported as context managers via the `with`
>   statement: on exit, standard file descriptors are closed, and the
>   process is waited for.
>
> ```
> with Popen(["ifconfig"], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
>     log.write(proc.stdout.read())
> ```

Comment: thank you for your response, I updated my question. But still the same problem